# How to obtain logged in user information from outside Phabricator domain?

Tags: javascript, php, cors, phabricator

In short, I have a Pharbicator setup on a domain A, but then I have to implement a service on domain B which relies on the Pharbicator.

So this is the story, I am trying to gather information using the Phabricator Conduit `user.whoami` API to see whether the current user is logged in. But due to various reasons I couldn't make it. I would like to know what is the correct way of doing so.

I have tried three methods but they all did not work. Here is what I tried

**Method 1**: Using Ajax Request
What I did is just to fire an POST Ajax request with the api token

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user.whoami', 
    method: 'POST', 
    cache: false, 
    data: 'api-token='+app.PHABRICATOR_APIKEY
}).done(function(response) {
    console.dir(response);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

This method does not work (as expected) because it is a CORS request, and the Phabricator server does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Although I can add that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but somehow this requires modifying the Phabricator source code so I would consider this as the last solution I would do.

**Method 2**: Using a PHP as proxy and inside use curl to request for it. So the whole request will be like `Client Browser <-> PHP Proxy Script <-> Phabricator`
This method is actually able to send the request and get response. But the information is wrong as it returns only the user of the API key.

If I understand it correctly, the `curl` is not having my browser session, so there is no way for it to really know who I (the browser client) am in Pharbricator. So I assume then the API will just fallback to use the information of API key and thus return information not I intended.

**Method 3**: Using the PHP library `__phutil_library_init__.php` provide by Phabricator

```
require_once '/var/www/html/phabricator/libphutil/src/__phutil_library_init__.php';

$api_token = PHABRICATOR_APIKEY;
$api_parameters = array();

$client = new ConduitClient('http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
$client->setConduitToken($api_token);

$result = $client->callMethodSynchronous('user.whoami', $api_parameters);

return $result;
```

Again this is nothing special, just a direct copy of code from the documentation. But again it is returning only the user the API key belongs to. And I think it is just the same as what method 2 is behaving.

I am thinking if I am understand the Conduit API in a wrong way. And more importantly I would like to know how I should implement the whole architecture so that it can gather information using the current browser session. Thank you.